# Android studio's Create new activity is very slow

Tags: android-studio

I'm not sure why. Whenever I try to create a new activity it takes forever for Android Studio's create new activity pop-up to show anything but a blank white screen. Sometimes the screen doesn't load up at all, no matter how long I wait. Has anyone else has this issue?

Comment: Maybe just because Android Studio acquires a lot of RAM and your RAM free space is very slow so Android Studio becomes slow. In this case you do not have other option than upgrading your RAM

Comment: Checking task manager shows that AS is only use ~730 MBs of ram, which is a lot, but not enough to justify the massive slowdown i'm seeing. I've go 4G of ram, so i'm not even using 60% of what I have?

Comment: So how much free RAM do you find in Task Manager ? (Overall free space of RAM, or percentage of full ram)

Comment: Then maybe because your CPU is very busy. Check it usage percentage. Also check also disk usage (with resource monitor). If disk is very busy, your PC can become slower when manipulating files.

Comment: neither of them are very active

Comment: In your `C:\Users\<Username>` folder, there android studio configuration folder. Take backup of them then delete them. And retry to see if problem is solved. If not solved you can restore your old folders you deleted.

Comment: That didn't help, I had to resort to writing the files by myself =(

Comment: No. As a final solution, uninstall then install again. If didn't help, report the problem to them (By Help menu)

Comment: The solution is to resize the window.

Comment: Hmmm very strange. You should report this bug to them